# Multiple values from array in query with hapijs

Tags: node.js, hapi.js, joi

I want to have valid query like that `countries=fr,be`

I tried this: 
`countries: Joi.string().valid(['fr','be'])`

But this allows only to have `countries=fr` or `countries=be`, but not multiple comma separated values. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [regex](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v13.6.0/API.md#stringregexpattern-name--options) like so:

```
var list = ['fr', 'be']; // your counrty codes
var joinedList = '(' + list.join('|') + ')'; // prepare RegExp cases
var regex = new RegExp('^' + joinedList + '(,' + joinedList + ')*$') // the thing in itself
```

Then:

```
countries: Joi.string().regex(regex).required()
```

It would match any country code in `list`, alone or in a comma-separated list. I added `required()` as I believe `valid()` implicitly makes the field required as long as you don't allow `undefined` value.